# How can I disconnect clients from a Vino VNC server at will?

Tags: 10.04, vnc, vino, vinagre

I have vino set to ask before allowing connections, but I'm unaware of how to disconnect clients once they are connected.

The only way I've found to disconnect them is disable sharing (and then re-enable it).

It seems there should be some sort of connection manager to list and disconnect clients at will, but I'm unable to find anything like this.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should enable the notification area icon using `vino-preferences` (Desktop Sharing Preferences). Then, once the icon appears, you can right-click on it and select "Disconnect client-name".

That's all :-)